# how to perform a calculation on the output of cat and then format it

Tags: bash, cat, watch

I don't know shell scripting at all, but I have this

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now
```

which gives me the output in milliwatts, which i would like to format as watts and use in watch

```
watch -t -n 5 cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now
```

Comment: Can you post contents of `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now`?

Comment: **Close voters**: The question is clear enough. `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now` is a well known Linux file, and contains power values in Watts, which OP wants to convert to mW values. This is a very simple text processing question. At least leave a comment what exactly is unclear about it.

Comment: Except this file is not always present.  It is not unreasonable to request example input and desired output; particularly for text processing questions.  Even more particularly for simple ones so that the answer can be used to teach to fish rather than to fetch a fish.  Or because some such questions end up being X/Y Problems.

Comment: @DopeGhoti You mentioned it's not always present. How so ? It's been on all Debian/Ubuntu based-OS I've ever used.  Aside from BSD-variants, of course, I don't recall ever using it there. It's supposed to be one of the common files on Linux, at least.

Comment: It is, for example, not present on my Ubuntu Server host running 16.04.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bc` (with the flag to do floating point division):

```
echo "$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now) / 1000" | bc -l
```

Comment: thank you that was exactly what i was trying to do but o couldn't work out how to format it for the pipe to bc

Answer (score 0):

You could always resort to awk for parsing file and performing calculations:

```
awk -F '=' '/POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW/{print $2/1000}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now
```

This operates on using `=` as separator for columns. Typical awk format is to perform action in `{}` for lines that match pattern in `//`. So, for line that has  `POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW`, take out column 2 (`$2`) and print it after dividing by `1000`.

As for doing that with `watch`, it may be a bit tough to use [due to quotes](https://askubuntu.com/q/971114/295286). I'd suggest running it as:

```
watch "awk -F '=' '/POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW/{print $2/1000}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now"
```

Comment: @Ourjamie  Welcome, glad to help.